# Как вывести названия всех файлов в определенной папке. xcode c++

Tags: c++, xcode, файлы, macos

Имеется папка с наличием в ней текстовых документов например: a.txt, b.txt.
Как вывести названия этих файлов?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

...

cin.get();

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На современном C++ что-то вроде этого:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __cpp_lib_filesystem
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
#else
#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;
#endif

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    std::cerr << "provide an argument";
    return 1;
  }

  const auto dir = argv[1];
  for (const auto &f : fs::directory_iterator(dir)) {
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Компилировать с `-std=c++17` и скорее всего `-lstdc++fs`.

См. также http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator.

Comment: c++17 слишком новый язык, есть что-то подобное на старом?

Comment: -std=gnu++17 у меня используется, я не уверен, но вроде как -std=c++17 пока может не работать

Comment: @goldstar_labs У меня GCC 5.4.0, `std=c++17` работает, если дополнительно подключить `libstdc++fs`.

Comment: @Ainar-G, надо обновляться) спасибо за инфу

Answer (score 2):

Если без C++17, вполне работает так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>

int main() {
    if (argc < 2) {
        std::cerr << "Provide an argument";
        return 1;
    }

    DIR *dir = opendir(argv[1]);
    if (!dir) {
        std::cerr << "Could not open directory";
        return 2;
    }

    dirent *entry;
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != nullptr) {
        std::cout << entry->d_name << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел вариант через терминал:

```
system("ls | tee text.txt");
```

Потом выводим данные из этого файла с помощью fstream.

Comment: Извините, а уже предложенные решения действительно не помогли? Если нет, то почему?

Comment: Я не говорил, что они не помогли, я просто предложил еще один вариант, возможно он не совсем правилен, но рабочий и подходит для данной задачи.

Comment: Если ни один ответ не отмечен как принятый, значит никакой из них не помог. А дав ответ, вы это только подтвердили.

Comment: Можно даже проще -- `system("ls *.txt")`. Или, если хочется прочесть в программе, то `FILE *f = popen("ls *.txt", "r"); if (f) {char file[1024]; while(fgets(file, 1024, f)) { .... } pclose(f);}...`