# Запись названия всех файлов директории в массив c++

Tags: c++, linux

Есть директория, например /home/tester. Как мне из нее считать названия всех файлов в массив, ну или в файл средствами c++(14) без прибегания к "system"?

Comment: [Filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

Comment: или функции из dirent.h, если чисто на линукс

Comment: Если что, dirent.h работает и на винде на mingw (но не на msvc).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести названия всех файлов в определенной папке. xcode c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/804386/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b5-xcode-c)

Comment: [man opendir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html)/[man readdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Нужна поддержка c++17

```
#include <experimental/filesystem> //либо #include <filesystem>
#include <algorithm>

namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;   //либо соответственно std::filesystem; 

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    //инициализация вектора
    std::string path = "/home/tester";
    auto it = fs::directory_iterator(path);
    std::vector<fs::path> array;
    std::copy_if(fs::begin(it), fs::end(it), std::back_inserter(array), 
    [](const auto& entry) {
        return fs::is_regular_file(entry);
    });

    //запись списка в файл
    std::string filename = "~/file.txt";
    std::fstream stream(filename, stream.trunc | stream.in | stream.out);
    if (!stream.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Не удалось открыть файл " << filename << std::endl;
    } else {
        for (auto & p : array)
            stream << p.string() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Забыл уточнить ,что поддержка только c++ 14=(

Comment: @volnistii11 обновляйтесь, хватит в пещере сидеть :) Всё то же 
самое можно найти в `#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>` и `boost::filesystem;`

Comment: @margif к сожалению нет возможности, я где-то читал, что это работало и на более ранних версиях, но при помощи библиотеки boost, не знаете ли вы что-то об этом?

Answer (score 0):

Если надо закинуть в массив, то можешь просто из вектора все перекинуть в массив через итератор. Это мой рабочее решение:

```
int files_in_directory(string way_, vector <string> &spisok_failov_)
{
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
HANDLE hFind;
int kolvo = 0;

hFind = FindFirstFile(way_.c_str(), &FindFileData);
while (FindNextFile(hFind, &FindFileData) != 0)
    spisok_failov_.push_back(FindFileData.cFileName);
FindClose(hFind);
kolvo = spisok_failov_.size();
return kolvo;
}
```

Реализация:

```
        vector <string> spisok_failov;
        spisok_failov.clear();
        int k = 0;
        int i2 = 0;
        string st = "Res/Textures/";
        int image_max = files_in_directory(st + "*", spisok_failov);
        for (int i2 = 0; i2 < image_max; ++i2) {
            string str = spisok_failov[i2];
        }
```

Comment: Спасибо, но для этой программы нужна библиотека windows, которой у меня нет=(

Answer (score -1):

Например вот так:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char var[400];

    fp = popen("ls //Users//Shared", "r");
    while (fgets(var, sizeof(var), fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", var);
    }
    pclose(fp);

    printf("%s", var);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А чем это лучше `opendir`+`readdir`?

Comment: Скорее, это аналог `system()`, который ТС просил не предлагать